# How to generate a video by looping an image and then concat with another very long video without re-encoding using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have an image and a very long video (1.5h).
Now I want to generate a heading video about 5 seconds by looping the image, and then concatenate it with the long video. Since the video is long, I don't want to re-encode the videos.
I have tried to generate the heading video using

```sh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -c:v libx264 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p head.mp4
```

and then

```sh
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c:v copy concat.mp4
```

where the list.txt contains

```sh
file head.mp4
file longvideo.mp4
```

I have tried these operations on two machines.
On one machine, the concatenated video has no audio. Moreover, it stucks at 5-10 seconds and directly jump to 11s.
On the other machine, the video and audio are not synchronized.

To provide more information, I have checked the codecs of the two videos by

```sh
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name \
  -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 xxxxx.mp4
```

Both of them are h264.

My question is, how to generate it correctly with ffmpeg? If it is hard using ffmpeg, is there any method to do it fast? As far as I know, Adobe Premiere and Final Cut Pro do not export as fast as I expect because they re-encode the videos.

Comment: Both videos to be concatenated must share [these same attributes](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32603). Yours do not match. If you show the **complete** output of `ffprobe -show_streams longvideo.mp4` I can give you an answer you can copy and paste.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since the output is too long, I have attached the output to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/f-sky/longvideo_ss/main/show_streams_output.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 5 -i image.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=48000 -vf "scale=1920x1080,setsar=1,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -video_track_timescale 16k -shortest head.mp4
```

This will match `longvideo.mp4` [attributes required for proper concatenation](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32603).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It almost solve my problem. By the way, since I may preprocess the longvideo.mp4 before concatenate with the heading, such as cutting off some beginning frames using 'ffmpeg -i xxx.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 ...', can you tell me which parameters should I pay attention to?

Comment: @LinghaoChen Does the answer not completely solve the problem as stated in the original question? Regarding the preprocessing: I need to see your complete command to be able to make any additional suggestions.

Comment: Yes, the answer does completely solve my original question. For the preprocessing: I use the command:
```
ffmpeg -i longvideo_before_proprocess.mp4 -ss 00:09:07 -c copy longvideo.mp4
```
And then concat the longvideo.mp4 with the heading video. It works nearly perfect, except that the heading video becomes 7s after concatenation, with the audios perfectly concatenated, it seems like the heading video occupies the first several frames of the longvideo (only video, not audio). More infos are [here](https://github.com/f-sky/longvideo_ss/blob/main/preprocess.md).